# How do I display the title of the entities to which the user has no access?

Tags: 7, entities, display-suite

I created a new content type with entity references to standard pages. I am using the [Taxonomy Access Control](https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_access) module to control the access to these pages.

When users view a node of that content type, they unfortunately do not see page titles for which they do not have access (the title is a teaser). I want all entities to be listed (with the links to the pages), even if the users do not have access to actual page. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make sense to list links because if users follow it they will only see the Access denied page.

But you can create a Views list with the titles and disable the node access check for those Views. You have to be really careful not to reveal something unintentionally!

In d8 you can disable the node access check under **Query options** > **Disable SQL rewriting**, it may be called differently in D7 but it will be in approximately the same location.